# Create list of dates given list of date ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a column of start dates and a corresponding column of end dates like so:

```
Start Date        End Date
6/26/06           7/2/06
7/1/06            7/8/06
8/17/06           8/21/06
8/17/06           8/20/06
9/3/06            9/9/06
9/6/06            9/8/06
```

How do I get a new column with all dates within these start/end date ranges, inclusive of start date and end date?  So I'd want a new column that looks like this:

```
New Column
6/27/06
6/28/06
6/29/06
6/30/06
7/1/06
7/2/06
7/1/06
7/2/06
7/3/06
7/4/06
7/5/06
7/6/06
7/7/06
7/8/06
8/17/06
8/18/06
8/19/06
8/20/06
8/21/06
8/17/06
8/18/06
8/19/06
8/20/06
9/3/06
9/4/06
9/5/06
9/6/06
9/7/06
9/8/06
9/9/06
9/6/06
9/7/06
9/8/06
```

I have tried the tutorial here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2659-excel-list-all-dates-between-two-dates.html, but I'm not sure how to replicate it with more than 1 row of Start Date/End Dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have your data starting in column A1, with the word `Start` in `A1` and `9/8/2006` in `B7`.

Further assume that you want your output in Column D.  Make A helper column, called `Index` in column E.

Put `=A2` into Cell `D2`.  Put `1` in Cell `E2`.

In Cell `D3` put:

```
=IF(E2=0,"",IF(E2=E3,D2+1,OFFSET($A$1,E3,0)))
```

In Cell `E3` put:

```
=IF(D2=OFFSET($A$1,E2,1), IF(OFFSET($A$1,E2+1,0) = 0, 0,E2+1), E2)
```

Then just copy `D3` and `E3` down.  Once you have reached the last row, column `E` will show `0` and column `D` will be blank.